# CQ5 - Google analytics issue for vanity URLs

Tags: redirect, google-analytics, adobe, aem, vanity-url

In our project, we have configured vanity URLs such that the user can enter the vanity URL in the address bar which will redirect them to the original URL.

For example:

If user inputs 'http://www.abc.com/partner', it will redirect them to 'http://www.abc.com/us/en/partners/become-a-partner.html'. This mapping is configured from Felix console and CQ takes care of the redirection.

But when such redirection happens by CQ, the request header does not have 'referer' field (Referring URL is blank in the google analytics), because of which Google Analytics report treat vanity URL redirection same as direct traffic.

**Basically, We want to see the segment of vanity traffic to be treated separately from other direct traffic.**

Any workaround available to achieve this? Please share your details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The built-in CQ5 vanity URL feature might be what you're looking for.  Set this [Page Property on the Basic tab](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-5/wcm/page_create_edit.html#Basic).  I think you will want to uncheck the Redirect Vanity URL checkbox to get the referrer header that you want.
[image]